A natural intractable geometrically inspired double-sum
Consider the following geometric setup: at every $(m,n)$ with $m$, $n$ both even, place a unit circle. Then we invert this entire setup through the unit circle at the origin. How much of the area of the unit circle at the origin do the inverted other circles cover? I have deduced that this number is equal to $$\sum_{(m,n) \in \mathbb Z^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}} \frac{1}{(4m^2+4n^2-1)^2}.$$
I've tried elementary methods for this, but have zero idea whatsoever. This screams complex analysis, but I tried Poisson summation with no luck. Any ideas?

Nothing "geometric" about that sum. It is just a double sum.

$$\sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{\left(4m^2+4n^2-1\right)^2}=1+\frac{1}{64}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\psi'\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{16n}\right)-\psi'\left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{16n}\right)}{n^2}$$
where $\psi'(z)$ is the trigamma function.

@ThomasAndrews Geometric in the sense of "showed up from a geometric context," but fair enough.

Can you share with us the context? At first I thought this might have some relation to the Weierstrass $\wp$ function, but then I noticed the terms in the bottom are squared. If those terms were not squared, you would just be missing $\sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda} -1/\lambda^2$, which is just some number, and this would be $\wp(1)$ for the square torus with lattice $2,2i$. Such half-periods have been computed. As is, I don't think anything I've just said is useful, though.

Heal, use "geometry-inspired sum" rather than "geometric sum," which has a very particular meaning.

@ThomasAndrews Sure, I've updated it.

@A.ThomasYerger Place a unit circle at every $(m,n)$ with $m$, $n$ even integers; this gives us a lattice of circles, each tangent to its neighbors. If we invert every circle in this setup about the unit circle centered at 0, we get a bunch of shrinking mutually tangent circles inside the unit circle. This sum arises as the ratio of the area of the inner circles to the area of the unit circle.

If $f(k)$ is the number of ways to write $k$ as the sum of two squares of integers, this can be written as: $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{f(k)}{(4k-1)^2}$$ $f$ is a multiplicative function, but I'm not sure where to go from there. If it was $k^2$ in the denominator, we might get some kind of answer as a factorization. The $(4k-1)^2$ makes it trickier.

Is there a reason for there to be a simple expression? If you're interested, here is an integral representation:$$\sum_{m\in\mathbb Z^D\setminus{0}}\frac1{4||m||_2^2-1} = \int_0^{+\infty}te^t\big(\theta(i4t/\pi)^D-1\big)dt$$ with $\theta$ the Jacobi theta function
